# how to create a form popup-modal in magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, modal-popup

here I want to create a modal pop up when the button was a click, by using block file how can I pass the modal link through this below code...

```
 public function getMainButtonsHtml()
{
    $html = parent::getMainButtonsHtml();//get the parent class buttons
    $addButton = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')
        ->setData(array(
        'label'     => 'Add Amount',
        'onclick'   => "setLocation('redirect-url')",
        'class'   => 'amount'
    ))->toHtml();
    return $addButton.$html;
}
```

Note: `'onclick'   => "setLocation('redirect-url')"`,  ----> here i want to pass the link ,Wheather it is possible???If yes please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a module first, then after create a `requirejs-config.js` file at `app/code/Vendor/YourModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
         'myjs': "Vendor_YourModule/js/myfile"
      },   
    shim: {
    'myjs': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
}
```

You need to create `myfile.js` in `app/code/Vendor/YourModule/view/frontend/web/js/myfile.js`

```
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: 'mymodal1',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });
        }
    );
```

Then your phtml file should look like:

```
<div data-mage-init='{"myjs": {}}'>
    <a href="#" id="click-me">Click Me</a>
</div>


<div id="popup-modal" >
    yes I am the modal.
</div>
```

Also you can refer to this link for more help:

[Modal widget](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html)

Comment: How can i link this file via button on block(onclick function), weather there is any possiblities to add??

Comment: You mean that you have a button on block ??? but in my example you can make button in `phtml` file and do whatever you want...

Comment: Okay i show you another example from scratch, which may help you....

Comment: ok sir..........

Comment: Hello sir , can you give me an example how to prepare 2 columns layout using ui-component, I already created it, but when i click to edit it cannot fetch details...So how can I prepare the block and controller part  for this????

Comment: Brother you should raise another Question for this ... :)

Comment: How can i generate layout with 2 columns  like in customer module.....

Answer (score 0):

First, create a configuration file `module.xml` in `/app/code/Example/M2Modal/etc/` directory and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Example_M2Modal" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

Now, create the file `registration.php` in the root directory of the module `/app/code/Example/M2Modal/` and insert the following code into it:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(
  ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Example_M2Modal',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create a layout and a template file, so that the directories look like this:

`/app/code/Example/M2Modal/view/frontend/layout/`
`/app/code/Example/M2Modal/view/frontend/templates/`

Now, create a `default.xml` file inside the layout folder of your module and add the following code to it:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:View/Layout:etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main">
            <block class="Example\M2Modal\Block\Example" template="example.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the code above, you will see a block defined in the main container, which extends the `Example\M2Modal\Block\Example` block (a block that we will create later).

Now, add the `example.phtml` file in templates folder and insert the following code to it:

```
<div id="modal-content">
    <?php echo $block->getContent(); ?>
</div>
<button id="example-modal-button" data-mage-init='{"example-modal": {"target": "#modal-content"}}'>
    Open modal
</button>
```

Here, use the `data-mage-init='{“example-modal”: {“target”: “#modal-content”}}’` attribute (a declarative notation) to add a JavaScript component in `example.phtml` template.

Now, add a JS file to initialize and execute the component.

Create a file `example-modal.js` in `/app/code/Example/M2Modal/view/frontend/web/js/` directory and add following code to it:

```
define([
        "jquery", "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal"
    ], function($){
        var ExampleModal = {
            initModal: function(config, element) {
                $target = $(config.target);
                $target.modal();
                $element = $(element);
                $element.click(function() {
                    $target.modal('openModal');
                });
            }
        };
        return {
            'example-modal': ExampleModal.initModal
        };
    }
);
```

You will notice that the `example-modal.js` code uses the define function at the top. This function is from RequireJS, which is an array of dependency. In the above example, `example-modal.js` uses jquery  and `Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal`.

The `example-modal.js` file should be declared in the `requirejs-config.js` file because this config file is used by RequireJS.

So, create the `requirejs-config.js` file in `/app/code/Example/M2Modal/view/frontend/` directory and add the following code to it:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'example-modal': 'Example_M2Modal/js/example-modal'
        }
    }
};
```

As the Example\M2Modal\Block\Example block is already defined in the layout file, create the `Example.php` block file in the `/app/code/Example/M2Modal/Block/` folder with the following code in it:

```
<?php
namespace Example\M2Modal\Block;
class Example extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getContent() : string
    {
        return 'Dummy content';
    }
}
```

Finally,

- Enable the module
- Run setup upgrade command
- Clear the Magento 2 cache

That’s it.

The window looks like this:
[image]

Want want something like this ???
[image]

Comment: how can i use this for backend

Comment: If you want to do this in you own custom module then instead of `/frontend` use `/adminhtml`

Comment: Raji tell me exactly what you want to achieve, I've updated my answer with an image tell me you want something like that....

Comment: No sir... i have create a button above the custom grid ...So that when i click the button i want popup form..But here i would not use xml file..I prepare my grid via block file only.. So that I am asking..

Comment: okay i'll try to help you out...

Comment: Have you added button successfully above the custom grid???

Comment: yes sir..  public function getMainButtonsHtml()
{
    $html = parent::getMainButtonsHtml();
    $addButton = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')
        ->setData(array(
        'label'     => 'Add Amount',
     'onclick'   => '',
        'class'   => 'task'
    ))->toHtml();
    return $addButton.$html;
}

Comment: here i want to action when onclick the button.....How to pass modal url inside the button onclick function

Comment: <img src="https://www.4shared.com/photo/uIqe8rxHgm/11_online.html " width="100" height="100">

Comment: See this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132628/how-to-create-custom-modal-ui-form-component-with-multiple-fieldset-and-field

Comment: ok sir.. Here any possibilities to add modal file via onclick function

Comment: i can't find the specific blog to achieve what u want, now all you have to do is to pick something from every blog and help yourself out, here is another blog, https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-button-in-magento2-admin-grid/ also https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-multiple-layers-of-modal-in-magento-2/

Comment: ok sir i will try

Comment: Go to Catalog>Product>Add Product, when you hit `Add Attribute` a popup appear try adopt this....

Comment: ok sir.. Catalog>Product>Add Product, when i hit 'add attribute' if i want to add modal pop form and grid which connecting with another database table , then how can i write the code...